# EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN when create an array?

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a tableview,, that use for several purposes. Inside `didselectRowAtIndex` delegate
I allocate an `NSArray` and initialize with some values.

`NSArray *param=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:selectedCell.textLabel.text,status,selectedCell.tag, nil];`

But this line gives an error `BAD_ACCESS_code= EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN`. What is the reason for this and how can I solve this

`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      NSArray *param=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:selectedCell.textLabel.text,status,selectedCell.tag, nil];

      if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedTableRowAUTOCREATION:)]) {
          [self.delegate selectedTableRowAUTOCREATION:param];
      }
  }
```

`

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `selectedCell` and its properties are not `nil`?

Comment: How are you inserting selectedCell.tag i.e. an NSInteger into the array without compilation error or warning? If you are using ARC then you surely should get an error saying "Implicit Conversion of NSInteger to id is disallowed in ARC". In No-ARC there should be a warning.

Comment: Tnz @Puneet that was the problem. I converted it into NSNumber. Then it solved. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedCell.tag`'s value isn't an object. You can't put it into an array.

If you need to keep track of the identifier, you need to box it into a NSNumber, by doing something like `@(selectedCell.tag)` -- and then when you need to access the value, you can do `[number integerValue]` to get it.